# Can I dynamic crop two input video then stack them using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make an effect of switching back and forth between two videos.

I tried to dynamic crop two input video then stack them using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=iw:'2+(mod(n,ih))':0:0[a];[1:v]crop=iw:'ih-2- 
(mod(n,ih))':0:'2+(mod(n,ih))'[b];[a][b]vstack=inputs=2[v]" \
-map [v] output.mp4
```

Skip 2 pixel to prevent crop zero.

But the output video is not what I want. It seems '(mod(n,ih))' is zero all the time.

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: crop does not support variable output dimensions unless set via commands (which should be rectified, but I digress). Are you trying to carry out a vertical wipe? If yes, are the videos the same dimension?

Comment: @Gyan Yes. I trying to carry out a vertical wipe. And the input videos are in the same resolution.